# 'inform' vs 'inform upon'

Tags: prepositions, difference

> [[Source:]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_from_ignorance) Arguments that appeal to ignorance rely *merely* on the fact that the veracity of the proposition is not disproven to arrive at a definite conclusion. These arguments fail to appreciate that the limits of one's understanding or certainty do not change what is [true](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_from_ignorance). **They do not *inform* upon reality.** That is, whatever the reality is, it does not "wait" upon human logic or analysis to be formulated. Reality exists at all times, and it exists *independently* of what is in the mind of anyone.

I am guessing [OED Online's Definition 8b](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/95559?rskey=MCXyEM&result=6&isAdvanced=false) as the apt definition for ***inform*** in the foregoing:

> III. 8b. Of a quality, principle, etc.: to be the determinant principle of; to give a thing its essential quality or character; to inspire, animate; to pervade. In later use more generally: (of an experience, etc.) to influence, to affect.

Yet OED appears mum on **inform upon**. So what are the similarities and differences? What would happen if **upon** were omitted here? 
I know that as prepositions, [upon = on](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/upon).

Comment: The best thing to be said about the *English* in that passage is that it is nowhere near as bad as the *logic* in that passage. I suggest that you put it from your head, and seek to emulate neither.

Comment: @ruakh Read the entire article. The logic of the article is very sound - though its very thrust is to dismiss false logic arrived at through poor reasoning.

Comment: @Tetsujin: It's a Wikipedia article, with the various parts having been written and modified by different people over time; so it doesn't make sense to take "the logic of the article" as a proxy for the logic of a specific passage. *This passage* is nonsense written by an idiot. Think about it; if someone says, "What? There was no riot last night. No one's mentioned one", would you seriously think, "Oh, I see. He thinks that reality is shaped by what he has heard"? Of course not; you'd just think "He's wrongly assuming that everyone would be talking about that."

Comment: The text was added by an anonymous whose IP was 192.138.70.245 on 19 January 2011. For the difference between revisions, see: http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Argument_from_ignorance&diff=408835791&oldid=408833452.

Comment: I'm pondering adding [tag:pretentious-writing] to this question. That's really the only context you could ever see this usage in.

Answer (score 1):

It is an archaic meaning of "inform" in the sense "to create an impression on something", like a fingerprint on moist clay.

This trope, a commonplace in philosophical writing, would ultimately go back, I think, to medieval scholasticism at the intersection of metaphysics and epistemology (and from there back to Aristotle); the "form" of something was its essence, that which made it to be what it was. *Does the mind go out and alter that which it knows? Or does that which is known create impressions on the mind?*  Yadda yadda yadda.

They (the limits of our understanding) do not create an impression on reality. They do not change reality.

Answer (score -1):

I think the "upon" is relatively meaningless in that context, and is used to make the pattern of words flow better, and/or avoid the confusion of "inform reality" suggesting "telling information to reality." (Meanwhile introducing its own confusion...)

It may also be in parallel with the next sentence: *That is, whatever the reality is, it does not "wait" **upon** human logic ...*

Another possibility might be that he initially wrote "impose upon reality" -- or meant to write that, but mis-remembered the term and wrote "inform upon" instead.